# How to make ajax post call to the json file using jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I need to make an ajax call and post some data into a file. So I am using Tomcat server for this. I have tried something like this. But this is not making any changes. Here's my code:

```
 var request = $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/ajax/ajax.json',
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: details,
      success: function(details) {
        alert("submitted");
      }
 });
```

And I am not able to post values into JSON file. 
Please Guide me how to proceed. Is there any method to resolve this.

Comment: Do you receive any error in console? What does `console.log(details)` prints if it is written as the first line in `success` function? And, surprisingly, why would you want to make a `POST` request just to get a JSON file. Did you try it with `$.getJSON`?

Comment: I am not getting any error. Also in the console this is displaying - POST 
XHR 
http://localhost:8080/ajax/ajax.json

Comment: json file donot handle post or get requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Json file does not support POST/PUT/DELETE calls. You need to have a separate controller call for handling ajax requests.

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: Do I need to write separate API for 'save' action?

Comment: YEs you need to write a separate API for that ajax